# Choose the best way to get the number of comments for posts from Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question about the preference of choosing the table design in the database. 
First of all, I have three tables for Users, Posts, Comments 
this schema showing the tables: 
this user schema :

```
    CREATE TABLE `Users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `fullname` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
      `profileImg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `appPackage` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `token` text NOT NULL,
      `gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  ALTER TABLE `Users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`);
```

this Posts schema :

```
    CREATE TABLE `Posts` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
      `background` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `country` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `countryCode` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `CommentsCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `likes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

   ALTER TABLE `Posts`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     ADD KEY `users_post_userId_fk` (`userId`);
```

this comments schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `Comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `commentText` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Comments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `users_comments_userId_fk` (`userId`),
  ADD KEY `users_comments_postId_fk` (`postId`);
```

I want to query the Posts table, and each query brings 10 rows with comments count for every post.
Which is the best choice?
Querying the Posts table with joining to get count of comments like this :

```
SELECT * ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Comments
        WHERE Comments.postId = Posts.id) AS commentsCount
FROM Posts
ORDER BY Posts.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Or create a column `commentsCount` in the posts table that contains the number of comments for each post .

and Create a trigger linked to the comments table where, when inserting new comment, one number in the commentsCount is increased and when delete comment one number is decreased in `commentsCount` .
The query becomes only a posts table to get posts and comment count :

```
SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Posts.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the schema of your tables as text, not as image. Otherwise, we can't copy/paste to rebuild the tables

Comment: Short answer : Do it with query. What one can get with calculations should be get with calculations. Otherwise, you are duplicating informations. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against storing derived information in the `post` table. This would go against normalization best practices (and will be painful to maintain).

Information about comments belong to their own table. Whenever you need to count the number of comments per post, you can either use a correlated subquery as suggested by you:

```
SELECT 
    p.* ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments c WHERE Comments.postId = Posts.id) AS commentsCount
FROM Posts p
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

But if you are dealing with a large number of posts this might become inefficient, so you can also `join` the `Posts` table with an aggregation query on `Comments` like so:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(c.commentsCount, 0) commentsCount
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT postId, COUNT(*) commentsCount
    FROM Comments
    GROUP BY postId
) c ON c.postId = p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to know whether my suggestion about trigger is working, or is it ineffective?

Comment: @Sy4tech: yes, a trigger would work, but I would recommend against it for the afformentioned reasons...

Answer (score 2):

There are pros and cons for both variants:

- Adding another column breaks normal form. This is a problem not only in theory: Your write load on the `posts` table will increase drastically.
- Calculating the post count each time does create quite a load, but is a very clean option.

Both will work fine on a moderate number of posts and comments, but I recommend you explore a different approcach, if you scale to a higher post/comment frequency:

- Use an ethereal but fast cache (such as memcached) to store the post counts.
- If a post comes in, ignore the cache
- If a comment comes in (or is deleted), just delete the cache item for that post
- If a comment count is requested, look into the cache - if it isn't there calculate it and put it into the cache.
- You can use the built-in expiry mechanisms to keep the comment count cache at a manageable size while still having a very high hit rate.